# Health cloud - changeset?

Tags: change-set, health-cloud

Is it possible to use change set in health cloud? I cannot access it for experimental purpose and free of cost? Can someone help me here and let me know if changeset is possible in health cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Health Cloud Deployment involves below

1. Managed Package of Health Cloud that you get from Salesforce once you sign the contract.
2. Standard Objects, Settings, and Features
3. Some Unmanaged Extension Packages.
4. Other Customization you add. This will all be Metadata essentially.

For 3 and 4 you can definitely use the changesets to move the Metadata. For the 1 use Managed Packages.

For the second one some components can be moved through changesets and few components will be manual replication in PROD.